# Windows Media Player 12: Enabling the Deskband?

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player

**Is it possible to enable the "Deskband" in Windows Media Player 12 (on Windows 7)?**

While I recognize it wasn't everyone's "cup of tea", I found it very useful, and have grown to rely on it when listening to music.

Answer (score 5):

It appears to be gone in favor of the new functionality the taskbar thumbnails provide. You can now skip tracks and pause music directly from a toolbar underneath the WMP thumbnail.

Answer (score 4):

I too missed the deskband when switching to Windows 7, but I've now switched to the **Zune** software, which does have this feature:

[image: Zune Deskband Player]

Comment: Thanks! This looks like it will be a fantastic substitute for WMP in Win7.